# rgb values and pixels

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

def normalize_brightness(img: Image) -> Image:
    """

```
 Normalize the brightness of the given Image img by:
```

1. computing the average brightness of the picture:
       - this can be done by calculating the average brightness of each pixel
         in img (the average brightness of each pixel is the sum of the values
         of red, blue and green of the pixel, divided by 3 as a float division)
       - the average brightness of the picture is then the sum of all the
         pixel averages, divided by the product of the width and height of img
2. find the factor, let's call it x, which we can multiply the
      average brightness by to get the value of 128.
3. multiply the colors in each pixel by this factor x
   """

   ```
   img_width, img_height = img.size
   pixels = img.load()  # create the pixel map
   h = 0
   for i in range(img_width):
       for j in range(img_height):
           r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
           avg = sum(pixels[i, j]) / 3
           h += avg
   total_avg = int(h / (img_width * img_height))
   x = 128 // total_avg
   r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
   pixels[i, j] = (r * x, g * x, b * x)
   return img
   ```

   I am a little lost as to what I am doing wrong can someone help?

Comment: can you add what errors or issues you are running into?

Comment: use Shift operator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259031/java-increase-brigthness-of-int-color-with-bit-shifting

Comment: Also OpenCV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609098/how-to-fast-change-image-brightness-with-python-opencv

Answer (score 2):

You really should avoid `for` loops when image processing with Python whenever possible because it is seriously slow, verbose, harder to read and more likely to contain errors. Try to use vectorised Numpy functions, or OpenCV or PIL built-in functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def normalize(im):
   """Normalise brightness of image"""

   # Convert to Numpy array
   na = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)

   # Calculate average brightness
   avg = na.mean()

   # Calculate factor x
   x = 128 / avg

   # Scale whole array as float since likely fractional
   na *= x

   # Convert back to PIL Image and return
   return Image.fromarray(na.astype(np.uint8))

# Load image and normalize
im = Image.open('start.png').convert('RGB')
result = normalize(im)
result.save('result.png')
```

This code runs in around 800 microseconds on my machine whereas any version with a `for` loop requires around 70x longer.

Input image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation code to get the factor seems okay, processing every pixel to get the average of sum of averages.

However, your *modification* code to adjust the brightness is not done within a similar loop so it will operate on *one* pixel, and I'm not even sure that pixel is even *within* the image. You should do that within a loop as well:

```
for i in range(img_width):
    for j in range(img_height):
        (r, g, b) = pixels[i, j]
        pixels[i, j] = (r * x, g * x, b * x)
```

This should replace the third-last and second-last lines of what you have at the moment (between `x = ...` and `return ...`). So what you would end up with is:

```
img_width, img_height = img.size
pixels = img.load()  # create the pixel map
h = 0
for i in range(img_width):
    for j in range(img_height):
        r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
        avg = sum(pixels[i, j]) / 3
        h += avg
total_avg = int(h / (img_width * img_height))
x = 128 // total_avg

# == New stuff below
for i in range(img_width):
    for j in range(img_height):
        (r, g, b) = pixels[i, j]
        pixels[i, j] = (r * x, g * x, b * x)
# == New stuff above

return img
```

---

A few other things to look in to:

First, I'm not sure if returning `img` is the right thing to do here, unless `pixels` is a reference to (not copy of) the pixels in the image. You may want to check up on that as well.

Further, it *may* be possible that the value for `[rgb] * x` gives you something *more* than 255 for certain input data sets. If that's the case, you probably want to clamp them into the range `0..255` to ensure this doesn't happen. Something like (replacing the "new stuff" in the code above):

```
for i in range(img_width):
    for j in range(img_height):
        # Get original pixel.

        (r, g, b) = pixels[i, j]

        # Scale with upper limit.

        r = min(255, r * x)
        g = min(255, g * x)
        b = min(255, b * x)

        # Replace pixel with scaled one.

        pixels[i, j] = (r, g, b)
```

Comment: yes because for some reason when I put the modification inside the nested for loop I get a zero division error

Comment: @Jack, you can't put it inside the *current* loop set because you'll divide by `total_avg` which hasn't been set yet. You need *another* loop set.

Comment: so basically when I do my modification I am only modifing (total_avg) the average of ONE pixel and not the total average of all the pixels? And if so how would the for loop be to fix this?

Comment: @Jack, the `for` loop and whree to put it has been added to the answer.

Comment: where? I still just see the version before it

Comment: okay I have changed my code in the question to the format in which you said but I still get the division error and therefore need the for loop to fix.

Comment: @Jack, if you're getting `/0` errors, you need to isolate where the zero is coming from. That has nothing to do with your mis-processing of pixels when adjusting the image. The most likely case is that `total_avg` is set to zero for some reason.

Comment: yes that is the case once I isolated its the total_avg which is 0 for some reason. How can I fix this? I have also added my current code again in the question.

Comment: @Jack, you should ask yourself before editing any question: is this going to invalidate any answers already posted? If so, you should either constrain the edits to adding *new* information (leaving everything else there) or just ask a new question with a link back to this one. Editing questions in such a way as they invalidate answers destroys the whole intent of SO as a Q&A site. In any case, your edits were still wrong in that you were adjusting the brightness within the first loop. You *cannot* do this at that point since the end of the first loop is the earliest time you know ...

Comment: ... what factor to apply. It has to be done in two *distinct* loops, as per this answer. My suggestion is to use that second code block in this answer, it'll be the correct basis for what you're trying to do.

Comment: that code block doesn't seem to work for some reason. I also added the min function to it which is min(255, r*x)...... but when I return it nothing happens and the image is just the same as before

Comment: @Jack: okay, did you *read* the paragraph beginning "First, I'm not sure if returning img is the right thing to do here"? You may want to check on that since the pixels may be separate from the original image.

Comment: Secondly, it should be fairly easy to put in some `print` statements to see what the brightness-changing factor is and how it affects each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

At first, thanks to [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) for sharing his answer.

I would just like to improve on the answer.

The calculation of the average can be optimized using list comprehension like:

`x = 128 // (sum([sum(pixels[i, j]) / 3 for i in range(img_width) for j in range(img_height)]) / (img_width * img_height))`

So my complete answer will be:

**Normalize the brightness of the given Image**

```
img_width, img_height = img.size
pixels = img.load()  # create the pixel map

x = 128 // (sum([sum(pixels[i, j]) / 3 for i in range(img_width) for j in range(img_height)]) / (img_width * img_height))

for i in range(img_width):
    for j in range(img_height):
        r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
        pixels[i, j] = [min(255, r * x), min(255, g * x), min(255, b * x)]

return img
```