# Normalizing the brightness of an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
def normalize_brightness(img: Image) -> Image:
    """
    Normalize the brightness of the given Image img by:
    1. computing the average brightness of the picture:
        - this can be done by calculating the average brightness of each pixel
          in img (the average brightness of each pixel is the sum of the values
          of red, blue and green of the pixel, divided by 3 as a float division)
        - the average brightness of the picture is then the sum of all the
          pixel averages, divided by the product of the width and height of img
    2. find the factor, let's call it x, which we can multiply the
       average brightness by to get the value of 128

    3. multiply the colors in each pixel by this factor x
    """
    img_width, img_height = img.size
    pixels = img.load()  # create the pixel map
    h = 0.0
    for i in range(img_width):
        for j in range(img_height):
            r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
            avg = sum(pixels[i, j]) / 3
            h += avg
    total_avg = h / (img_width * img_height)
    x = int(128 // total_avg)
    for i in range(img_width):
        for j in range(img_height):
            r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
            pixels[i, j] = (min(255, r * x), min(255, g * x), min(255, b * x))
    return img
```

So basically that is my take on the following function but for some reason it does not work. I believe my calculations and steps are what the docstring has told me to do but I am lost where to go from here.

Comment: You already asked this question and received answers. If the average brightness of all your images is 192, what do you think your scale factor `x` will become if you use `x = int(128//192)` ?

Comment: 0 which is the issue I am trying to fix. How can I fix this so that I don't get this error

Comment: Read the answer that I gave to your previous question... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60945820/2836621